# How can i fix cookies in PHP?

Tags: php, html, css

i want to include cookies in my website in php but i don't know how to do this.

i've tried to include them with sessions but it didn't work.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?>
```

i expected to keep me connected but it didn't. What else do i need to add in my code to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `setcookie()`

[Take a look at the PHP documentation for examples.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Edit:

To explain, before you can read a cookie, you need to set the cookie somewhere. You must call `setcookie()` before you output any information (e.g. echo or html before the php script tags) or there will be an error.

`setcookie()` also does not determine whether a user accepted the cookie. If a user has cookies disabled in browser, you would not be able to set or retrieve a cookie.

Since cookies can be manipulated, they tend to be a very bad place to store whether a user is logged in. Generally, sessions are better for that.